# How does Guava com.google.common.net.InetAddresses get hostname without reversing DNS?

Tags: java, guava, android-guava

I do not understand how does it work. Can anyone explain me that from jni level? Does it call [getnameinfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738532(v=vs.85).aspx)?

https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.java
[image: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.java]

ok. How can i get name from an udp connection?
[image: name of sender]

Answer (score 0):

It does not get the hostname at all.  `ipStringToBytes` converts an IPv4 or IPv6 address into raw bytes and uses that to call `bytesToInetAddress` which calls [InetAddress.getByAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByAddress-byte:A-) which returns uses a raw IP address.